# How to make log4j not to prints stdout, thread name

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jboss7.x

Why does log4j print:

```
17:58:30,623 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-5)
```

The complete message is:

```
17:58:30,623 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-5) 2012-12-09 17:58:30.623 [INFO] com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AuthController#login - A message
```

I am using JBoss AS7 and I have exclude log4j like:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

And my `log4j.properties` is:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CA

log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%p] %c#%M - %m%n
```

I want to print the message as:

```
2012-12-09 17:58:30.623 [INFO] com.edfx.adb.web.controller.AuthController#login - A message
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because JBoss STDIO wraps stdout and stderr and the log4j `ConsoleAppender` outputs to stdout.

You can accomplish the same thing your trying to do by configuring the logging subsystem instead of using a log4j.properties file. Using the logging subsystem there is also no reason to exclude the dependency in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">

    <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%p] %c#%M - %m%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </console-handler>

    <!-- other handlers and loggers -->

    <root-logger>
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
</subsystem>
```